# mysql if function - subquery as a condition

Tags: mysql, subquery, conditional-statements

I believe the following query is self explanatory:

```
SELECT IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable > 0, 'yes', 'no');
```

Why doesn't it work? And how should I correct it?

Comment: Possibly because it is invalid syntax. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Could you be more specific, Asad? I am well aware that it is an invalid syntax

Comment: use if, then else.. REf http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html

Comment: Sure, you aren't evaluating the subquery before using the comparison operator on it, which can be done by enclosing it in parentheses. Additionally, you don't need `>0`, since 0 is falsy anyway.

Comment: Dear close voters, I'm surprised by your decision. Could you explain what did you find wrong with the question? I'm doing something that seems for me perfect, and find that it doesn't work. Obviously there is something that I don't know / don't see. What's more natural than asking others who will probably immediately know?

Comment: In this particular example I found out that sub queries need to be enclosed in paranthesis, and that I somehow missed it in my mysql education. I learned this from Michael's answer.  So what did you find wrong here?

Comment: Going to agree with shealtiel and go a bit farther, close voters clearly have been overridden by I presume John Topley's edit from last year.  closed note should be changed or removed, thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Enclose the subquery in parentheses:

```
SELECT IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable), 'yes', 'no');
```

Comment: Thank you! 
Do I always have to enclose any subquery in parantheses?

Comment: Yes. See here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html

Answer (score 5):

It this what you want?

```
SELECT IF(COUNT(*) > 0, 'yes', 'no') FROM mytable;
```

---

1:

```
SELECT
  t1.*,
  (SELECT IF(COUNT(*) > 0, 'yes', 'no') FROM mytable) AS col1
FROM
  table t1;
```

2:

```
SELECT
  t1.*,
  t2.*
FROM
  table t1,
  (SELECT IF(COUNT(*) > 0, 'yes', 'no') AS col1 FROM mytable) t2
```

Comment: Thanks, but no, as this is intended to be part of a more complicated query

Comment: Then, two other variants - check the answer.

Comment: Thank you for multi variation answer !

Answer (score 3):

If your query is more complex and this is only a reduced problem, I think this is the better solution for you

```
SELECT IF ( (SELECT COUNT(*) AS counter FROM myTable HAVING counter>0) , 'yes', 'no')
```

so you can do more complex check (i.e. counter > N or multiple conditions)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable) > 0, 'yes', 'no');
```